# What is this low growing plant with pink flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers, weeds

I'm still getting to know my garden. I see these pink flowers growing and can't decide whether they're growing at random or they were planted intentionally. What type of flowers are they? Should I get rid of them along with the purple ones?

[image: pink flowers]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pink flowers are Phlox subulata, a variety of anyway, not sure which cultivar, there are a lot of them. Its a perennial, often evergreen depending on variety, usual height and spread is 6 inches by about 20 inches, though you can cut them back after flowering if they spread wider than you'd like.

The blue, though, is most likely Veronica persica - a wildflower or weed, depending on your point of view, and they appear to have spread through the Phlox, so it might be wise to try to remove some of that before it tries to take over completely.

UPDATED ANSWER:

Its pointed out in a comment below that what I've named as likely Veronica persica may be Glechoma hederacea - and it may well be. That one roots at the nodes, unlike Veronica, and smells vaguely minty when crushed. Either way, it needs to be controlled or eradicated. Glechoma is edible - but Veronica persica is not.

Comment: Agree on the phlox, but I think the blue flowers are Glechoma hederacea. Either way it's the type of plant that is liable to get out of hand if allowed.

Comment: Good point, updated the answer in response.

Comment: Thank you! You're right about the blue, it did get out of hand before I had a chance to control them. I guess I should try to get rid of them without touching the pink ones.